# Table is rendered in the end of the page instead of it's required position if it was sent to Jinja2 template as a text

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to create a website via Python and Flask.

I'm sending a text with a table to render with Jinja, and this table renders at the end of the page even though it's in the middle of the text.

I'm new to the Flask and this breaks my head

Text is sent to the template with render_template

`return render_template('test.html', text=text')`

In the template I display this text with

```
{% autoescape false %}
    {{ text }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Text example:

```
 '...You decide what action the creature will take and where it will move during its next turn, or you can issue a general command, such as to guard a particular chamber or corridor. If you issue no commands, the creature only defends itself against hostile creatures. Once given an order, the creature continues to follow it until its task is complete.<br/><h5> Animated Object Statistics 
    <br/></h5><table class="table table-hover mt-2 table-sm" style="max-width: 500px"><thead><tr><th></th><th> Size </th><th> HP </th><th> AC </th><th> Attack </th><th> Str </th><th> Dex </th><th></th></tr></thead><tbody><br/><br/><tr><th></th><th> Tiny </th><th> 20 </th><th> 18 </th><th> +8 to hit, 1d4 + 4 damage </th><th> 4 </th><th> 18 </th><th></th></tr><br/><tr><th></th><th> Small </th><th> 25 </th><th> 16 </th><th> +6 to hit, 1d8 + 2 damage 
    </th><th> 6 </th><th> 14 </th><th></th></tr><br/><tr><th></th><th> Medium </th><th> 40 </th><th> 13 </th><th> +5 to hit, 2d6 + 1 damage </th><th> 10 
</th><th> 12 </th><th></th></tr><br/><tr><th></th><th> Large </th><th> 50 </th><th> 10 </th><th> +6 to hit, 2d10 + 2 damage </th><th> 14 </th><th> 10 </th><th></th></tr><br/><tr><th></th><th> Huge </th><th> 80 </th><th> 10 </th><th> +8 to hit, 2d12 + 4 damage </th><th> 18 </th><th> 6 </th><th></th></tr></tbody> <br/><br/>An animated object is a construct with AC, hit points, attacks, Strength, and Dexterity determined by its size. Its Constitution is 10 and its Intelligence and Wisdom are 3, and its Charisma is 1. Its speed is 30 feet; if the object lacks legs or other appendages...'
```

Screenshot from the website:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fMrw.png